# goodness of fit in regression/ models include a significant number of insignificant variables

Tags: multiple-regression, tobit-regression

I have performed analyses using two different regression models, multi-nominal regression and Tobit regression.

In the first model I measured the impact of 9 variables on choosing travel mode while in the second model I addressed the impact of these variables on trip time duration. After submitting to a peer review journal I am asked to answer some comments of reviewers. One comment is:

(Multi-nominal regression model) "models include a significant number of insignificant variables. This approach misrepresents the magnitude, and possibly in some cases the sign of other coefficients. This needs to be addressed."

I showed the significant codes in my paper by these signs: Signif. codes: *α ≤ 0.10, **α ≤ 0.05, ***α ≤ 0.01

[image: dependent variable is travel mode( in three categories: car,public transport, walking/reference category is car) and there are 9 independent variables.]
What does he/she mean by this comment?

I think I was questioned because I have some variables that are not significant but one category of them is significant. For example, the chi-square of income and education is not significant but one category of them (low level income), or (high level education) is significant. However, the sig is under 0.05. How I should I convince the reviewer?

The second question that I should to answer is about the Tobit regression which I performed in Stata. I addressed the effect of several variables on time duration of work, shopping and leisure trips to city centre. I am asked to answer this comment:

(Tobit reg) "it is found that the goodness-of-fit of the leisure model is about 6 times for shopping and 4 times for working purpose travels. What are significant variables that could describe the travel time of work and shopping trips and overlooked? Why are the same group of variables that describe the travel time of leisure trips significantly better than work and shopping trips? Clarification is needed". 
Pseudo R2 for work, leisure and shopping trips are  0.082   0.32    0.052 respectively. the numbers of each kind of trip are 1375, 756, and 545 respectively.
[image]

To tell the truth, I do not have enough knowledge of regression models; I just run the models and I find it very difficult to answer these comments. 
I would be grateful if anyone could help me answer these comments.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Please edit your post to include more information on the actual research question at hand, the model you fitted (preferably in equation form), and some output.  It is difficult to give any useful advice without seeing what the table in question look like.  For example, if you had 25 regressors, how many of those were dummy variables, how many were continuous, etc. and how many of the non-significant variables were dummy vs. continuous.

Comment: It is also quite normal to have only one or some, but not all dummy variables in a set to be significant.  Recall that the interpretation of dummy variables is in relation to the omitted (reference) category.  The reviewer might be concerned about multicollinearity in your model, of which one of the symptoms is a lack of statistical significance and very large p-values for model covariates.  Finally, for tobit interpretation, I recommend Cameron and Trivedi's (2009) _Microeconometrics Using Stata_ from Stata Press

Comment: Thanks for your consideration to my questions. I added some more details about my models and also uploaded two pics of my results. Hope it makes my questions more clarified.

Comment: There are various minor confusions on both sides here. Trivially, the term _multi-nominal_ is not a standard substitute for _multinomial_ in my view (although the term does make sense) (fixed in edits). Also minor: in text visible on editing you mention 1 independent variable and 9 dependent variables. These terms are the wrong way round. Also, the reviewer's wording "a significant number of insignificant variables" is clumsy as the first significant just means "a lot" while insignificant does carry its technical sense.

Comment: On bigger issues I agree with @MarquisdeCarabas. It's standard to include a bunch of indicators (dummies) that collectively capture a categorical variable even if some do not show up as significant at conventional levels. You can find explanations of this in good modelling texts, e.g. IIRC http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/ Otherwise  answer comments about too many insignificant predictors by leaving out predictors that don't have a good rationale. My guess is that the reviewer may overstate the risks of a few useless predictors but the only way to be sure is to try it.

Comment: It is harder to comment on your use of Tobit models. The statement "goodness-of-fit of the leisure model is about 6 times for shopping and 4 times for working purpose travels" makes no sense to me. The reviewer seems to be asking for substantive comments on which predictors explain what, which seems fair to me, and beyond our scope here. But why did you use Tobit regression at all? If it's because durations are necessarily positive, it seems to me that there are better functional forms out there, especially generalized linear models with logarithmic link.

Comment: As a different kind of comment: I am intermittently an author, a reviewer and a journal Editor and have experience of all these levels. It's fine to re-submit to an Editor and say that some comments by reviewers are not clear to you. Then an Editor has choices, e.g. to ask the original reviewer to clarify. But inevitably your chance of a better decision does depend on how far you can go  to meet their suggestions (unless you can show that those suggestions are wrong or irrelevant).

Comment: A purely personal opinion is that $\alpha = 0.1$ is unduly generous as a critical level. and leads to over-complicated models that claim too much. But I don't work in this field where you may have to bend over backwards to get any kind of half-decent fit.

Comment: You've reversed my edits from multinomial to multi-nominal. Why did you do that? I'd be impressed if you can find one textbook from reputable authors and publisher that allows it as a standard term. Sorry, I think that's very misguided on your part. Multi-nominal is not just a misspelling; it's not the standard term.

Comment: Thanks for considering to my question. I thought I should edit my question text,  I did not know you edited this term, I misunderstood about your comment sorry. As I admitted in my first comment, I have no knowledge about these models and that's why I put comment here.

Comment: I have to express surprise that you're trying to publish using models of which you say you have "no knowledge". If you're hoping or expecting for a  complete tutorial as answer then your question is too broad.